# How to log to same file from multiple child processes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a main process which is running an infinite loop and calls other scripts in certain intervals. Today main script and other scripts use different log files. I am looking for a solution where all the child processes log to same file. I went through this https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/network-logging.html. The only solution that looks feasible is running a separate logging server and the child processes can use "logging.handlers.SocketHandler" to send logs to server. Is there any other way other than using socket server?

The main script

```
def main_loop():
   # call other scripts in 15 seconds interval using 
     subprocess.Popen(scriptname, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                                close_fds=True,
                                preexec_fn=os.setsid)

if __name__ == "__main__":
     main_loop()
```

Other scripts

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    doSometing()
```

Comment: You want to store your logfile in server? if you just want to log the output from the script to single file. you can do this way   out = subprocess.run("test.exe",stdout=subprocess.PIPE, timeout=5, shell=True)
data= str(outStd.stdout.decode().strip()) , open a file and append the data into it

Comment: I want to store it in the local disk where the child processes are running. I can append the  string in a file but my concern is I will not get benefits of logging APIs like formatting etc.

Comment: What is the output from the script and what is the expected format you need?

Comment: In the child processes I want to do LOG.info(msg), LOG.error(msg), LOG.warn(msg) which will log the messages in /var/log/collector.log file.

Comment: /var/log i assume you are using unix/linux system. i am sorry I not sure is this what you need https://docs.python.org/2/library/syslog.html

Comment: I wonder if you  child processes could shell an os command to append to the log file and let the os handle multiple access.  (Not tried.)

Comment: I was able to solve this problem using SockerHandler https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/network-logging.html